# Pandas to_csv function formats minus signs to "â€“

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to save a dataframe to csv using the `to_csv` function but I get this weird output **â€“** format for the minus sign  (**'-'**). How can I avoid this?

The dataframe were categorized into bins using `pd.cut`

```
Trap1_Odds      Trap2_Odds        Trap3_Odds      Trap4_Odds
10.0+           3.0 – 3.99          10.0+         9.0 – 9.99
3.0 – 3.99        0.00              10.0+           10.0+
10.0+             10.0+             0.00            10.0+
7.0 – 7.99      3.0 – 3.99          0.00           3.0 – 3.99
10.0+             10.0+             10.0+         5.0 – 5.99
```

Output on my excel sheet

```
Trap1_Odds      Trap2_Odds        Trap3_Odds      Trap4_Odds
    10.0+           3.0 â€ 3.99         10.0+         9.0 â€ 9.99
    3.0 â€ 3.99       0.00              10.0+           10.0+
    10.0+             10.0+             0.00            10.0+
    7.0 â€ 7.99     3.0 â€ 3.99         0.00           3.0 â€ 3.99
    10.0+             10.0+             10.0+         5.0 â€ 5.99
```

Comment: Please include code and examples.

Comment: @vtasca I have updated the question with my dataframe table

Comment: ok, so you can find info : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55867822/when-running-python-script-i-get-%C3%A2%E2%82%AC-instead-of-a-hyphen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a different encoding when exporting your csv :

```
df.to_csv("file.csv", encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

PS : `utf-8-sig` is just an example. Not sure which one could work in your case. We need more details. But to start, try `utf-8`, `cp1252` or `utf-8-sig`...

Comment: thanks for your response  `cp1252` worked as expected.